# Get n-th data member of a struct

Tags: c++, reflection, c++17

To get n-th member of a `struct` without non-empty bases and w/o non-public members C++ now have a pretty way:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

struct filler { template< typename type > operator type (); };

template< typename aggregate, typename index_sequence = std::index_sequence<>, typename = void >
struct aggregate_arity
        : index_sequence
{

};

template< typename aggregate, std::size_t ...indices >
struct aggregate_arity< aggregate, std::index_sequence< indices... >, std::void_t< decltype(aggregate{(indices, std::declval< filler >())..., std::declval< filler >()}) > >
    : aggregate_arity< aggregate, std::index_sequence< indices..., sizeof...(indices) > >
{

};

template< std::size_t index, typename type >
constexpr
decltype(auto)
get(type & value) noexcept
{
    constexpr std::size_t arity = aggregate_arity< std::remove_reference_t< std::remove_cv_t< type > > >::size();
    if constexpr (arity == 1) {        
        auto & [p1] = value;
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            return (p1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else if constexpr (arity == 2) {
        auto & [p1, p2] = value;
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            return (p1);
        } else if constexpr (index == 1) {
            return (p2);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else if constexpr (arity == 3) {
        auto & [p1, p2, p3] = value;
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            return (p1);
        } else if constexpr (index == 1) {
            return (p2);
        } else if constexpr (index == 2) {
            return (p3);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else /* extend it by yourself for higher arities */  {
        return;
    }
}

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

int
main()
{
    using S = struct { int i; char c; bool b; };
    S s{1, '2', true};
    decltype(auto) i = get< 0 >(s);
    decltype(auto) c = get< 1 >(s);
    decltype(auto) b = get< 2 >(s);
    static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(i), int & >{});
    static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(c), char & >{});
    static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(b), bool & >{});
    assert(i == 1);
    assert(c == '2');
    assert(b == true);
    s.i = 2;
    s.c = '3';
    s.b = false;
    assert(i == 2);
    assert(c == '3');
    assert(b == false);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It is not as generic as one can want, but it is workable on `clang` from a current trunk.

It also currently not works for top level cv-qualified class (due to `clang` [bug](http://wg21.link/LWG2770)) and can't properly forward referenceness of the input (though, it can be implemented for non-`const` references), but latter is hardly desired by anybody at all (maybe there would be conversion of referenceness from xvalue to prvalue, whereas lvalueness should be still preserved).

What can I do it to improve the style and correcteness?

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BVYkYn68Hqds3bNL).

Comment: Interesting. I guess you meant `and w/o non-public members`. I think you should add that the struct actually needs to be an aggregate (i.e. no custom constructors, no virtual/private/protected base classes, no virtual functions, no default member initializers) (or have some very coincidental constructor set)

Comment: @Eichhörnchen Thank you for correction. Actually class may have constructors. Constructor with highest arity will be considered. In the case this arity should match the number of data members. Default member initializers are also not the problem. About virtual stuff you are right.

Comment: I mean "highest" in continouos integer sequence started from 1 (i.e. unary).

Comment: That's what I meant by "coincidental constructor set". There would have to be for every m from 1 to n, where n is the number of data members, exactly one constructor accepting m arguments, but no constructor accepting n+1 arguments and all the constructors mentioned would need to be non-explicit. I thought about wether it is possible to use SFINAE over `auto& [...] = value` to decide the number of members, but I think that doesn't work, because there is no way to get the statement into a template argument expression.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen It has been recently discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768517/structured-bindings-width).

Comment: I would not use keywords as names just like I would not use "password" as password. A potential concept name is better. `template <typename Aggregate...` instead of `template<typename type...>`

Comment: +100 for arity and +100 for the filler and +100 for using structured binding on a value as opposed to the function result. But I would make dedicated versions of `get` for non-const, const and rvalue references.

Comment: Why do you have an empty return in `get` on out-of-index? Why not simply one single `static_assert(index<arity>` at the beginning?

Comment: @PatrickFromberg I think it was just my omission. Anyways there is [boost::pfr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_pfr.html).

Comment: Yes, since version 1.75, that's why I did not know it. But good to know, I will align my implementation with that so I can port it later.